# Does a query plan always give the same result order?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

For a query that has no order by clause, will a given query plan always return results in the same order? I understand that a different plan may be chosen, but if the same plan is chosen, will that give the same result order? Essentially, what freedom does the query executor have to reorder the rows when executing a given plan?

Comment: The **only** (really: the *only*) way to get a guaranteed order is an `order by`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is this true even when you do not change data, table definition, indexes, do not run vacuum or reindex table (and similar)? I mean - I understand that we cannot determine in what order rows will be returned. But if we really do not change anything, is it still true, that rows can be returned in different order from one query execution to another?

Comment: @TomasGreif, Yes even then.  It usually doesn't happen, but it can.  For example if a seq scan detects a different seq scan of the same table already in progress, it might start at the same place, to make better use of caching, and then circle back at the end to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, results won't be returned in the same order, even without a plan change.
The query executor does not have to reorder the rows, it doesn't even order them in the first place.

For example, when rows come in disk order:

```
CREATE TABLE o(id int);
INSERT INTO o VALUES (1),(2),(3);
ANALYZE o;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM o;
                   QUERY PLAN                    
-------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on o  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=4)

SELECT * FROM o;
```

Result:

```
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
```

Let's update a row (without even changing the value):

```
UPDATE o SET id=2 WHERE id=2;
```

and rerun the same select:

```
SELECT * FROM o;
```

```
 id 
----
  1
  3
  2
```

Notice how the order has changed. Of course the plan is still the same:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM o;
                   QUERY PLAN                    
-------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on o  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=4)
```

Conclusion: the execution plan doesn't imply any order without `order by`.